# NSLog, how can I produce a fixed width output for different size fields?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I want to produce an output of data which will line up, but the fields can have different widths.

For example, one field is an INT, it can be from 1 character to 3 characters in length.

Is there a way to get NSLog to pad fields ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<2000; i+=50) {
    NSLog(@"%4d", i);
}
```

Where 4 is alignment.

Answer (score 2):

NSLog uses a plain old C string formatter. Nothing special apart from the format string being a `@"foo"` rather than a `"foo"`

Use http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

How about using tab characters to line things up? i.e. `\t`. Otherwise there's no way to get `NSLog` to do this for you and you'd have to roll your own way of doing it unfortunately.

Comment: so simple yet so effective, had to use 3x `\t` but this worked flawlessly